# Two rows from a table show as two different columns in another table after join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tables like:

Table A

```
tableA_key  BillToCustId SoldToCustId 
123         C1           C2
```

Table Cust

```
ID Name Type
C1 ABC  Bill To
C2 XYZ  Sold To
```

when I am joining the Cust table with Table A and adding columns in the query I want the solution to look like this:

Table A

```
tableA_key  BillToCustId BillToName SoldToCustId SoldToName 
123         C1            ABC        C2           XYZ
```

What I am getting:

```
tableA_key  BillToCustId BillToName SoldToCustId SoldToName 
123         C1            (null)        C2           (null)
```

The question is how can two rows in the Cust table be columns in table A?

Answer (score 1):

You can join twice:

```
select 
    a.tablea_key,
    a.billToCustId,
    c1.name billToName,
    a.soldToCustId,
    c2.name soldToName
from tablea a
inner join cust c1 on c1.id = a.billToCustId
inner join cust c2 on c2.id = a.soldToCustId
```

Possibly, you also want join conditions on `cust(type)`, like:

```
select 
    a.tablea_key,
    a.billToCustId,
    c1.name billToName,
    a.soldToCustId,
    c2.name soldToName
from tablea a
inner join cust c1 on c1.id = a.billToCustId and c1.type = 'Bill To'
inner join cust c2 on c2.id = a.soldToCustId and c1.type = 'Sold To'
```